# 64 bit Vivek's Virtual Camera

Tags: c++, video, filter, directshow

I have build 32 bit famous Vivek's VCam available here [http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm](https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam) and it successfully works and shows in 32 bit video conferencing software's like Skype and Zoom but when I build it int 64 bit it showed in graph edit but did not showed in 64 bit video chatting software's like Skype for windows 10, Bluejeans and Skype for business 64 bit.

Do anyone has experience in using 64 bit VCam project? Do I have to make some changes in code for 64 bit? please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a 64-bit filter, it will work only for 64-bit software which consumes video capture via DirectShow and not otherwise. There is not so much of this software around though.

See [Applicability of Virtual DirectShow Sources](http://alax.info/blog/1722) to get an idea where such 64-bit builds are applicable and what are the other options.

You will also find relative information in these older questions:

- [Virtual Driver Cam not recognized by browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923351/868014)
- [DirectShow filter is not shown as input capture device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222795/868014)

Comment: So my only option if want my virtual device to display in every software is building it in kernel mode. For this I am planning to create WDM driver using avstream drivers as starting point. If you can recommend any other help or better solution then please suggest.